# Why when I add a Bing map(My places) url in android webview not showing the route from .gpx file?

Tags: android, android-webview, bing-maps

I import a .gpx file in my places of Bing map. The .gpx file is a route. I check the "Turn on sharing." and "Let others copy items from this list of places." so I can share my Bing map  to another browsers and run well. The problem is that when I add the link to a android `WebView` I show only the map without my route on it. I do not want to use google maps because there is an error to the name of my city.
Please help, and I am sorry for my English.
Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like you are using the Bing Maps website. The issue you are having is expected. The Bing Maps website is not meant to be used in applications like this, that is what the developer API's are for. The GPS functionality that you see on the Bing Maps website is actually the old Bing Maps website which will be turned off in the near future. When you access the website on mobile it loads the new website which doesn't support GPX files.

If you want to use Bing Maps in your application you can use the developer API's and easily load in a GPX file. You can find a GPX module for Bing Maps along with code samples here: http://bingmapsv7modules.codeplex.com/

Comment: Thank you for your reply. My app is a Android app and i wont to use Bing maps. Ok , i will try to  use the developer API's. Am i to the right path? Thank you!

Comment: Yes, the developer API works well when hosted in a web view in an android app.